# As we go around the circuit, the total voltage drop must equal zero

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, electromagnetism, kirchhoffs-laws

I am studying an advanced mathematics textbook. One of the examples is within the context of an electrical circuit (a *series* circuit, I think). The example makes the following claim:

> As we go around the circuit, the total voltage drop must equal zero.

Can someone please explain what law/principle of physics this is, and elaborate on it a bit? My research indicates that it might be Ohm's law, but I'm too inexperienced with these concepts to link the formal description of Ohm's law to the above statement.

Thank you.

P.S. I'm not sure if my tags are appropriate, so feel free to edit with the appropriate tags.

Comment: Sounds like Kirchhoff's Voltage Law: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Oh, ok, so it's not Ohm's law?

Comment: No, Ohm's law expresses the relation between voltage, current and resistance, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Ok, thanks. After reading the Wikipedia article on Kirchhoff's laws, would the relevant one be Kirchhoff's voltage law?

Comment: Read my first comment again and note how the KVL says something about the **sum** of **voltages** in a loop.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Oh, sorry, I read over that part. Thanks again!

Comment: Interestingly, the text of Ohm's Law actually does not contain the word 'resistance'

Comment: @ThePointer  The units of the electric field are volts per meter.  Voltage is the integral of the electric field between two points.  Measuring the voltage between different points along a closed path in a circuit and adding them up is equivalent to integrating the electric field along a closed path.  The electric field is a conservative field, so it makes sense that the integral along any closed loop would be 0V.

Comment: @user4574 Ahh, now you're speaking my language. Good comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can someone please explain what law/principle of physics this is, and elaborate on it a bit?

It's more common sense than anything else. Kirchoff wrote it down first! Let's use an analogy:

- You are on the ground floor (Floor zero in Europe) of a large building (voltage = 0 V).
- You go up to the third floor in the lift / elevator. (Voltage = 3 V).
- You walk across that floor to the stairs. (Voltage is still 3 V.)
- You come back down to ground floor. (Voltage is zero again.)

No matter how you make the journey with any combination of stairs, lift or falling out a window the sum of the height changes will be zero when you arrive back at the start.

> My research indicates that it might be Ohm's law ...

No. This isn't directly related to Ohm's law.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of Kirchoff's Laws its the voltage law.

Consider a simple circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fx7IUV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

> Kirchoff's voltage law simply states that the sum voltages around any
>   closed path is zero

This is a formal stating of what should be obvious common sense.

To understand what this means I will introduce the notation \$ V_{12} \$ as meaning the voltage measured between 'N1' and 'N2' treating 'N1' as the positive polarity. \$ V_{23} \$ having similar meaning for 'N2' and 'N3' etc.

Now consider a closed path \$ N1 \rightarrow N2 \rightarrow N3 \rightarrow N5 \rightarrow N1  \$

All this is saying is \$ V_{12} + V{23} + V{35} + V{51} = 0\$

Or by noticing that \$ V_{51} = -V1 \$

because it's the voltage across \$ V1 \$ but with the opposite polarity

\$ V1 = V_{D1} + V_{R1} + V_{D2} \$

This is true of any closed loop so \$ V_{34} + V_{45} + V_{53} = 0 \$ and \$ V_{12} + V_{23} + V_{34} + V_{45} + V_{51} = 0 \$ for example.

---

Kirchoff has another law for current that simply states:

> The net current into any node is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's one of Kirchhoff's laws and since you include a tag "electromagnetism" it's worth pointing out that it's incomplete as you write it: the sum of all voltages as you go round a circular path equals the rate of change of magnetic flux through that circle.  Basically, magnetic flux changes introduce "anonymous" voltage sources in such circles that are located between no two nodes in particular.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "*the sum of all voltages as you go round a circular path equals the rate of change of magnetic flux through that circle.*"? You seem to be saying that if the magnetic flux is changing that the sum of voltages around the circular path will be non-zero. Can you give an example?